# install Tensorflow WARNING: Value for scheme.scripts does not match

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Below warning pops up when I try to install Tensorflow; Any advise on how to solve it?

```
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: C:\Users\osazo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\UNKNOWN
sysconfig: C:\Users\osazo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include
WARNING: Additional context:
user = True
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
```

Comment: can we see the command you have used to install Tensor Flow? also are you on the local machine or installing in Google Colab for example? the error you got there is on pip.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `pip` warning. You need to upgrade `pip`:

```
python -m pip install pip==21.0.1
```

However, as it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617), you can ignore such warning.

> First off, this specific class of warnings can be safely ignored. They
> were added to help pip's maintainers identify incorrectly
> patched/configured Python distributions provided by redistributors
> (eg: with your OS, or as part of $corp's VM/Docker images etc). You
> can read more about actionable steps for end-users, in
> [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244301/warning-messages-when-i-update-pip-or-install-packages/67250419#67250419).

Comment: The answers on the duplicate mainly suggest to _downgrade_ `pip` if you want to avoid the warning; but as noted, it is harmless.